# PHP code for website application form

Tags: php

I have built an application form on this page:
http://www.pazzle.co.uk/indulgence/recruitment.html

I know I need to program it to actually send the information and uploaded images to my email address upon submission but my PHP skills are not too good. Is there a PHP script available where I can just tweak values to work with my form or will I have to hire somebody to do this for me?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sending_emails.htm Google is your friend...

Comment: Do some research and find the best method for your needs. Copy/paste solutions are rarely the best. It's much more powerful to learn what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$to = "uremailaddress@website.com";
$subject = "You Have a Message From  ".$field_name;

$emailmessage = "From: ".$name."\n";
$emailmessage .= "E-mail: ".$email."\n";
$emailmessage .= "Message: ".$message;

$headers = "From: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($to, $subject, $emailmessage, $headers);
```